# "Unnatural" Hamiltonian systems from a statistician's perspective

Tags: statistical-mechanics, computational-physics, hamiltonian, simulations, complex-systems

I would like to learn more about "unnatural" Hamiltonian systems, that is, systems whose energies *cannot* be written as

$$H(p,q) = K(q) + U(p).$$

I have seen the term "natural" applied to systems that can be separated into kinetic and potential components, but have only come across the term "unnatural" in a few [scattered documents](https://web2.ph.utexas.edu/~morrison/T18MSRI1.pdf) online. An example is discussed in this very [interesting paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.1742) on the Kuramoto model.

I am particularly interested in techniques for sampling from the associated Gibbs distribution $f(p,q) = e^{-H(p,q)}$. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This post (v3) seems _too broad._